# Como cancelar o upload de um arquivo no storage do firebase web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, upload

Criei uma referência raiz de armazenamento no firebase web através do código abaixo:

```
var storageRef  = firebase.storage().ref();

var uploadTask = storageRef.child('img-tour/' +files[0].name).put(files[0]);
```

Porém, preciso cancelar o envio da imagem caso ela esteja no storage. Por exemplo, se a imagem `paisagem.jpg` estiver no storage do firebase e ao tentar enviá-la novamente, quero que o envio seja cancelado/interrompido. Como faço isso usando o firebase?

Answer (score 0):

primeiro você pode checar se o arquivo já existe.

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
const fileRef = storageRef.child('img-tour/' +files[0].name);
fileRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // Arquivo já existe. Não enviar
}).catch(function(error) {
  if (error.code === 'storage/object-not-found') {
     // arquivo não existe.
     upload();
  } 
});

function upload() {
  fileRef.put(files[0]);
}
```

ou pode criar um indice no banco de dados firestore se quiser evitar a checagem direto no storage.

Comment: Obrigada Paulo pela força. Fique na dúvida do que colocar em "// Arquivo já existe. Não enviar" ,em "// arquivo não existe." e em 'storage/object-not-found'.

Comment: caso a função getDownloadURL retorne uma url na promisse. quer dizer que existe um arquivo para caminho determinado. caso contrario a promisse for rejeitada e o erro vier igual 'storage/object-not-found' é porque o arquivo não existe no storage, logo você poderá enviar o arquivo.